# applicationDidFinishLaunching on thread

Tags: macos, cocoa, hockeyapp

I noticed a weird thing in my Mac app crash report.
Crash report says, `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called from main thread as well as from another thread.

As per my understanding, it should be called only from main thread.

Can anyone help, why this delegate is called from thread?

FYI, I am using hockey kit to report a crash.

Comment: Did you search your project to make sure you aren't calling that method manually elsewhere?

Comment: already did, not calling it from anywhere. It is called only as  NSApplication delegate